# Excel VBA display msgbox if cell is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I can't find the code for this anymore and I am seeing pages of codes suggested by other websites but I remember I only used about 3-5 lines of code for this.

How can I make it so when a cell is clicked, like if cell A1 is clicked then either a message box appears or a userform get's visible again?

Comment: what is your best solution so far?

Comment: My best and only solution so far is doing ALT+F8 :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this (in the worksheet)

```
'For double click
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Debug.Print "doubleclick"
End Sub

'for general changes    
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Debug.Print "change"

End Sub

'for selection changes
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Debug.Print "selection change"
End Sub
```

to detect. Target represents the range that is affected, so if you need, you can test that against the range you need evaluated (A1, for example). If you want to cancel the standard action that excel makes (for example set the cursor in the cell that you doubleclick), use `Cancel = False`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to work. `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) MsgBox "selection change" End Sub` I tried clicking on random cells in sheet1 but no message box appears. My goal is if the userform is missing, accidentally closed, or whatever reasons then they can just click cell A1 and the form should show. I don't want them to do ALT+F8 and I can't add buttons on the sheet since the sheet would contain dynamic contents.

Comment: Did you put it in the worksheet (not in a codemodule)? If that is your quest, why not use a button in the ribbon?

Comment: Yes inside ThisWorksheet EDIT: Sorry I meant ThisWorkbook

Comment: oh did you mean I should put it under sheet1?

Comment: You need the sheet, yes

Comment: It's working :) I placed the code inside the sheet1. All of my main codes are in ThisWorkbook